# Diffraction grating from reflection

Tags: optics, waves, interference, diffraction

We had an experiment in our physics lab where we used two grating materials one with 2500 lpi(say A) and the other with 15000lpi(say B).

Now when we shine white light on both of them we didn't get any spectrum in the **transmitted light** from A but we did get the pattern from B and my instructor told me that it had to do with the fact that the white light doesn't satisfy the coherence condition for grating A as the grooves are more spread out as compared to B.

But when I saw the light being **reflected** from both the gratings I could see spectrum in both of them !! When I asked this, he couldn't give an answer.

**So can someone explain why I was able to get the spectrum with reflected light but not with the transmitted one from grating A ?**

Here's a picture of **reflected pattern from both the gratings** :-

One with 2500lpi :-

[image: 2500lpi]

One with 15000 lpi :-
[image]

Comment: You can see "spectrum" in both, but clearly, the amount of dispersion in the one image is much greater than in the other. I can't answer how that relates to "coherence" though.

Comment: I don't understand why the 2500 lpi grating disperses light less than the 1500 lpi grating. Something is off.

Comment: @mmesser314 it's 15000lpi not 1500lpi